# How to redirect to index page of the same controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a search form. The parameters are sent to the controller via ajax request. If there is a result for my search, I want to redirect to another page and fill in the given parameters.
The first thing that fails, is to redirect to another page. I see in the debugger, that the correct action is called, but as result I can only see the default page.

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary param = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary();
//Result is evaluated before
//AjaxResult is wrapper class to display a "successful" / "error" message
if (ret.Data is AjaxResult)
{
    return ret;
} 
else 
{
    foreach (string p in form.AllKeys)
    {
        if (form.IsSet(p))
        { 
            //ViewData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,object>(p, form.Get(p)));
            param.Add(p, form.Get(p));
        }
    }
    //return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", param));  //previous try
    //return Redirect("~/Preise/Index"); //previous try
    return RedirectToAction("Index", param);
}
```

So even the 2nd try without the params lead to the default page instead of "Preise/Index" what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your making an ajax call. Ajax calls do not redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that because it's an AJAX request. Simply return param and do the redirect client-side in the response handler.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a hint. Due to a lack of time I returned the Request.URI and set that as the new location. This worked for me, too. But now I'd prefer a paramater free URL. But I think this is another question.